# Resizing the Managed AKS cluster node size or type destroys and recreates the cluster with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to resize the AKS cluster Nodes with Terraform, but everytime i does this the terraform destroys and recreates the cluster. I am able to resize the Cluster without disturbing the environment from Portal.

Is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is expected, AKS node size is immutable (at least it was last time I checked). if its not now - means terraform is relying on the outdated SDK calls.

btw, i cant see how you resize it, scaling works, resizing doesnt. scaling should happen without recreating

Comment: I wasn able to resize the node from Azure portal. There is an option to do that for the Agent.

Comment: that is not supported